# Retrieve path of photo from a ResultSet on java

Tags: java, windows, path, odbc, resultset

I am using an odbc connector.
I want to know how I can retrieve the path of photo from a resultSet in java.
on windows the path is with a single back slash (example: "`C:\test\rahul.jpg"`) so when I try this :

```
String str = resultSet.getString ("Ar_photo");
```

i got an error (`Error in assignment`).
because the path is not a valid string in java.
Knowing that i have tried to escape the value of path in database, but i noticed that this odbc connector doesn't support "replace" scalar function in sql query. 
How to proceed?

Here is the full stack trace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][Simba ODBC Driver]Error in assignment.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
at com.connector.sageConnection.ProductQueries.getCreatedProducts(ProductQueries.java:97)
at com.connector.sageConnection.ODBCConnection.synchronizeProduct_SG_sl(ODBCConnection.java:126)
at com.connector.sageConnection.ODBCConnection.synchronizeDataFromSage(ODBCConnection.java:86)
at com.connector.UI.LoginMethod.synchronizeData(LoginMethod.java:57)
at com.connector.UI.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:79)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you please add to your post the exact error/exception you're getting including full stack trace?

Comment: There's no problem with backslashes in strings in Java. A backslash needs to be escaped with a second backslash in a *string literal in Java source code* but that has nothing to do with a string coming from a database.

Comment: ResultSet is an object, not an instance of ResultSet. Consider providing more context to your code